# Finalizar processo por .bat sempre que o mesmo é iniciado

Tags: windows, batch, processo, helper, ms-dos

Bom dia!
Sempre que inicio o computador o *lindo* processo **GWX.exe** (o famoso processo **Instale o Win10**) é executado, sendo necessário ir ao Gerenciador de Tarefas e finalizar o mesmo.

Sendo assim criei um .bat com a seguinte linha de comando:

```
@echo off
TASKKILL /F /IM "GWX.exe"
```

Porém, ainda é preciso aguardar o processo **GWX.exe** ser iniciado e então iniciar o .bat para finalizar o processo.

---

Minha dúvida é, existe algum comando via DOS (nem que seja um .bat chamando outro .bat) que seja algo como:

`se processo GWX.exe estiver sendo executado
 então execute .bat`

Aguardo retorno, obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode Criar um comando .bat que da loop até que o GWX.exe seja fechado como

```
echo off

title Fecha o Arquivo GWX.exe a cada 10 seg

goto main

:main

eche Aguardando 10 Seg Para Fechar o Programa...

choice -c r -t 10 -d r >nul

taskkill -f -im GWX.exe

echo

goto main
```